# Passing Data from Controller to Razor Page, error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to show some data in my Razor page that I get from my controller, but I'm getting an error of `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` Here is how I am getting the data:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Timeline(TimelineModel model)
        {    
            model.Timelineinfo = _context.Timelineinfo.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM `thin-blue-lie`.timelineinfo WHERE Date = '2020-07-07'").ToList();           
            ViewData["Timelineinfo"] = model.Timelineinfo;

            return View("Pages/Timeline.cshtml");
        }
```

Here is TimelineModel:

```cs
public class TimelineModel
    {
        public TimelineModel() {}
        public IList<Timelineinfo> Timelineinfo { get; set; } 
    }
```

Here is the data it returns: [image]
I am trying to move that data into my Page by putting the following at the top of my page and accessing it by doing `@Event.City` for example.

```cs
@{
    var Event = ViewData["Timelineinfo"] as ThinBlue.Timelineinfo; 
}
```

However, I am getting the below error on the `var Event` line. I get the same error if I dont use `ViewData` and try to access stuff by doing `Model.Timelineinfo[0].City` Anybody know how I can fix this?

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Extra info: When I set a breakpoint at the `var Event` line, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRVtM.jpg) where both sides of the Event equation are null.

Comment: Curious to know why you'd want to use an async Controller Method to fetch data that is generated synchronously.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to await it properly, so I made it async and decided I'd leave it until I knew how to properly set it up.

Comment: Hi, @Bubinga, so  [model.Timelineinfo] is not null in action from your debugging? If it's not null, maybe you could try viewmodel, and I will also test later for you.

Comment: model.Timelineinfo = _context.Timelineinfo.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM `thin-blue-lie`.timelineinfo WHERE Date = '2020-07-07'").ToList();  Here you got null from sql.

Comment: @MichelleWang It is [not null](https://imgur.com/a/AlExnu2) after I took that screenshot I stepped forward and TimelineModel.Timelineinfo is not null either, it has all the information model.Timelineinfo does(as it should). Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am not reaching inside of ViewData["Timelineinfo"] far enough, so i'm not getting the thing titled ```[0]```. I don't know how to get to it either though.

Comment: @Bubinga try the solution I post in the answer. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `List<Timelineinfo>` to view in action, but casted as `Timelineinfo` in Razor page.

```
var Event = ViewData["Timelineinfo"] as List<ThinBlue.Timelineinfo>;
                                 //not cast as ThinBlue.Timelineinfo
```

Test codes in controller and Razor page:
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Screenshots of Test:
[image]

In the end, I suggest to change the names to avoid confusion.

```
public class TimelineModel
{
    public TimelineModel() {}
    public IList<Timelineinfo> Timelineinfos { get; set; } //not Timelineinfo
}
```

In controller,

```
ViewData["Timelineinfos"] = model.Timelineinfos;
```